# Importing an optional module

Tags: python, module, option-type

This is my file structure:

```
[mylibrary]
    __init__.py 

    [codecs]
        __init__.py < this is the file that we're talking about
        optional.py
```

Now I have this code in the marked `__init__.py`:

```
def load_optional_codecs():
    try:
        from mylibrary.codecs import optional
        # do stuff with optional
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

There is one problem with this. If the `optional` module contains an import exception itself it will silently fail. Is there a way to import an optional module without silencing any exception from the module?

---

This might seem like an obscure scenario, but I have gotten a nasty error because of the silenced exception and I would like to prevent that from happening in the future.

Comment: You can report the exception to the user or log it instead of `pass` in the `except` block, but if the import failing introduces nasty errors, I'd say it's almost certainly not "optional".

Comment: @Wooble: no, the `from mylibrary.codecs import optional` didn't fail. The problem was that the `optional` module imported a module which did fail (due to a programming error), but that error got silenced.

Comment: I can't understand the scenario. Obviously the `pass` could be replaced with some other exception handling. It seems that you are concerned about the case where trying to import `mylibrary.codecs.optional` causes an `ImportError` *due to* that module, in turn, trying to import something else (or explicitly raising the exception, or...) - as opposed to the case where it simply doesn't exist. What I don't understand is: **why should these two cases be handled differently**? Either way, the `optional` thing is not available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but you could check the message on the exception to determine what failed:

```
try:
    from mylibrary.codecs import optional
except ImportError, e:
    if e.message != 'No module named optional':
        raise
```

With this code, if importing the optional module fails, it is ignored, but if anything else raises an exception (importing another module, syntax errors, etc), it will get raised.

Comment: oh hah, that's pretty nifty. If no alternatives pop up I think I'll use this.

Comment: There would have been an alternative if the language designers had added an attribute e. g. `module` to `ImportError`. But they didn't, so this one seems to be the most feasible way.</rant>

Comment: @glglgl `ParsingError('Starting tag of </rant> not found')`

Comment: "With this code, if importing the optional module fails, it is ignored, but if anything else raises an exception (importing another module, syntax errors, etc), it will get raised." I can't understand the distinction that is being raised here. In my mind, "if anything else raises an exception" at import time, that **entails that importing the module failed**. To import something successfully means importing it without an exception in the top-level code.